# Undo or reset cookie for jquery lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I used the script described here: [Show welcome div only once per user / browser session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354301/show-welcome-div-only-once-per-user-browser-session)

My problem is that I need to know how to reset this cookie so the window can show up again for testing purposes.

Staging environment: http://rest.bsley.com/splash/

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use $.removeCookie of jQuery cookie plugin to remove your cookie.

Syntax: `$.removeCookie("cookiename");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.cookie("yourCookieName", null)
```