# How to trigger a jquery function only once in one page, per session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `jQuery` function, that produces an animation when my `index.html` is loaded.
I would like this animation to happen only once. If you go on an other page, then come back on the `index.html`, the animation should not happen.

But I would also like that when the index page is refresh, the animation is displayed.

I don't know if you get it...
Anyway thanks !

Comment: have you written any code?

Comment: I think you can try this http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: yes but it's way to huge to copy paste it... Consider it as an "onload" simple jquery function

Comment: _then come back on the index.html, the animation don't happen_, when you come back to the index the page will refresh??

Comment: no, if i come back on the index from within the site, there is no animation, but if i refresh the index, there is

Comment: Check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070877/jquery-run-once-per-session

Comment: No, if you come back on the index by a menu link, the page is not supposed to be refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascripts sessionStorage can make this possible.

This sessionStorage-variable will only be accessible while and by the window that created it is open. So, after closing the window, the sessionStorage variable will be undefined.

You can simply create this by using something like `sessionStorage.firstVisit = 1`.

Simple wrap this in an if-statement to check whether to show the animation or not.

For more info on this check http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute

Comment: I tried using the sessionStorage, it works for the animation not to be displayed if i come back on the index, but if I refresh, the animation won't display either

Comment: @keyloags for this, i would suggest to use $(window).unload(); function in combination with the sessionStorage described above

Comment: Could you give me an example ? I don't really know how to manipulate the unload() function...

Comment: I'm going to stick with the sessionStorage. It will refresh the animation only if the browser is closed, but I'll work with it ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one !!

```
 if (!sessionStorage.isActive) {
        $('.your-div').animate(); //write your code to animate
        sessionStorage.isActive= 1;
    }
```

Comment: I did try it, only I'd like that refreshing the index turn the session storage as it was the first time, displaying the animation

Comment: Can you share fiddle if you have any?

Comment: I don't have one, my code is a bit too heavy for it :/

Answer (score 0):

Use of sessionStorage may be helpful, You can save

```
animationContent = document.getElementById("yourID").innerHTML;
sessionStorage.setItem('animationContent', animationContent);
if(sessionStorage.getItem('messageContent')){
    yor animation function;
}
```

Or

## .one ensures this is done only once

```
$(document).once('ready', function() 
{
    Your Code here;
});
```