# Run function once per site/chrome session

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a program that when you visit the site, it shows the div, a button is pressed to hide it, and it isn't shown again until chrome is closed and reopened.

```
function check() {
  if (sessionStorage.alreadyClicked) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('disclaimer-container')[0].style.display = "none";
    sessionStorage.alreadyClicked = 1;
}
```

I've tried adding `sessionStorage.alreadyClicked` to by code as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070877/jquery-run-once-per-session) to no avail.

No matter what I do the div will always show. I'm looking a cross browser solution in the long term but as of now just chrome.

Comment: have you tried == >  sessionStorage.setItem('alreadyClicked ',1); 
and this is how you get it sessionStorage.getItem('alreadyClicked ')

Comment: `if (sessionStorage.alreadyClicked)` should have been `if (!sessionStorage.alreadyClicked)` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25070971). Also *logically* the code should be checking if something has *not* been clicked, then setting the `alreadyClicked`. Rather than only setting `alreadyClicked` if it was set.

Comment: _"and it isn't shown again until chrome is closed and reopened"_ - `sessionStorage` is limited to the individual _tab_ - if you close the tab, the page session is lost. Opening the same URL in a different tab, will also get that tab its own, individual page session. So for "until Chrome is closed and reopened", this won't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using IbraHim M. Nada's answer to compare the value of `alreadyClicked`

```
function check() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('alreadyClicked') != "y") { // Why wasn't I using != to begin with?
    document.querySelector('.disclaimer-container').style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector('.disclaimer-container').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Then I added `sessionStorage.setItem('alreadyClicked', "y");` to the hide function after clicking the button. This works flawlessly.

I also started using `querySelector` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: try to mark the answer that helped you as an answer

Answer (score -1):

From that same page:

“Be careful with sessionStorage because it can only store string values.”

Right now your if statement is essentially checking if that storage *exists*, which will always return true.

Try this instead:

```
function check() {
  if (!sessionStorage.alreadyClicked = “y”) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('disclaimer-container')[0].style.display = "none";
    sessionStorage.alreadyClicked = “y”;
}
```