# Wordpress page redirect. Main page adress but different destination

Tags: wordpress

I come here to ask about how to redirect from one page to another.

I have a main page and the greeting page (like a christmas greeting with some filling form). I want people who go directly to MAIN PAGE, to see the greeting page. And after that they push a button and go to normal page.

EXAMPLE:

Main page: www.test.com

Greetings page: www.test.com/greetings

How do I do it so that when people go to www.test.com, the browser shows them www.test.com/greetings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the WordPress admin area, then go to settings->reading and change Front page displays to a static page.  Select the "greetings" page from the drop down menu for "Front Page".

Comment: But in this way its become your homepage, how to make it redirected page. so how then direct visitors to normal homepage?

Comment: What it sounds like you are asking for will result in a constant redirect loop, no?  If you are sending people who visit www.test.com to www.test.com/greetings, and then redirecting them back to www.test.com, won't they just get forwarded again to www.test.com/greetings?  Can you clarify your request?

Comment: ok for example i have www.test.com and i have www.test.com/greeings. I want that when visitors go to www.test.com they should see www.test.com/greeting. But after they so that they push on bottom "Go to www.test.com. And they would be redirected to old page, not to the www.test.com/greetings again. Becouse by your example, www.test.com become a www.test.com/greetings. Is it any other way? :)

Comment: It's more involved... there are a number of ways to do it.  One, you can set a cookie in the browser to check if they've ever seen the welcome page before.  If not, send them there and change the cookie to prevent redirecting again.  Another option is to just pull the welcome page content into the main page and display it there, maybe in a modal or something.  It all depends on your coding abilities and what you ultimately want to accomplish.  Do any of these options sound viable?

Comment: sure, do :) thank you a lot :) Maybe know any tutorial of this? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354301/show-welcome-div-only-once-per-user-browser-session, or you can try https://css-tricks.com/redirecting-to-a-splash-page-but-only-once-with-cookies/.  The second link is probably more what you are looking to do.  There are tons of examples out there.  Let me know if you need help with any you attempt to implement.