# Hide div with jquery and cookies not hiding properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So I'm using this script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.cookie('noShowWelcome')) $('.welcome').hide();
  else {
    $("#close-welcome").click(function() {
      $(".welcome").fadeOut(1000);
      $.cookie('noShowWelcome', true);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<div class="welcome">
</div>
```

To show the div "welcome" only the first time a user visits my website and then to hide it forever.

For the cookies I used `jQuery.cookie javascript` as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354301/show-welcome-div-only-once-per-user-browser-session):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js

Everything works great. The only problem is that I still can not figure out how to avoid the hidden div flashing for a second and then hiding when users visit my website after closing the div "welcome". Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: by default, make it hidden by adding  `display:none;`

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that but display:none; hides the div even the first time the user visits my website. How can i avoid that?

Comment: write code in you JS to show when there is no cookie set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the FOUC, what you need to do is to use a small script to convert everything from CSS / Properties into JavaScript. For browsers that do not support `hidden` property, you can use:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".hide-me-by-js").hide().removeClass("hide-me-by-js");
  // Write your other conditional logic here...
});
```

```css
.hide-me-by-js {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide-me-by-js">Initially Hidden</div>
```

If you want to leverage the new `hidden` property (at a cost of browser compatibility), use the following:

```js
$(function () {
  $("[hidden]").hide().removeAttr("hidden");
  // Write your other conditional logic here...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div hidden>Initially Hidden</div>
```

#### Solution

In your case, it would be typically this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".hide-me-by-js").hide().removeClass("hide-me-by-js");
  // Write your other conditional logic here...
  if ($.cookie('noShowWelcome'))
    $('.welcome').hide();
  else {
    $('.welcome').show();
    $("#close-welcome").click(function() {
      $(".welcome").fadeOut(1000);
      $.cookie('noShowWelcome', true);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.hide-me-by-js {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<div class="hide-me-by-js welcome">Initially Hidden</div>
```

> **Note:** The demo will **not** work because the stack snippets iframe is sandboxed. Please just use the code and check in your system.

Added a [**Fully Working Code Demo**](http://output.jsbin.com/retavuzitu/1).

Comment: @AlivetoDie `Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.` So it's not our problem...

Comment: oh noah! (thats why it's better to use jsfiddle that is so badly unrecommended lately)

Comment: @FlashThunder True that, but the problem is they aren't indexed or versioned. `:(`

Comment: Is not working. It flashes the div for a second and then it hides even the first time.

Comment: @JohnGrischam I am unable to replicate that. Does it flash in the snippet above?

Comment: So the first visit div disappears after flashing for a second then flashes on every page as it previously flashed

Comment: @JohnGrischam Works fine for me here: http://output.jsbin.com/nadawahofo/1. Since you don't have the full HTML, the close button is what sets the cookie...

Comment: @JohnGrischam Fully working code: **http://output.jsbin.com/retavuzitu/1**.

Comment: Thank you for your help but flashing remains the same. I can not get rid of flashing for a second every time a new page or post is clicked.

Comment: @JohnGrischam Are you finding the flashing on the snippet or the code I have used or the link I have sent you? Confirm me that. Coz I am on a low end machine as well as a decent android mobile and I cannot find the flashing at all. Have you added the CSS too?

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much sir. I gave wrongly a block style to the welcome div which was overriding display none.

Comment: @JohnGrischam Ha ha... Glad that it helped you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Give it attr "hidden" by default and just show it when you need to.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!$.cookie('noShowWelcome')){
        $('.welcome').show();
        $("#close-welcome").click(function() {
           $(".welcome").fadeOut(1000);
           $.cookie('noShowWelcome', true);    
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome" style="display:none;">
Welcome
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that but display:none; hides the div even the first time the user visits my website. How can i avoid that?

Comment: @JohnGrischam I have answered that for you.

Comment: if (!$.cookie('noShowWelcome'))
        $('.welcome').show();

Comment: if (!$.cookie('noShowWelcome')) $('.welcome').show(); is not showing div. it still remain hiden